# How to import svg into antd -> Icon component

Tags: svg, create-react-app, antd

Hey I am trying to import my own svg into antd -> Icon component
like in the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/icon/) but i got an exception

> InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on
>   'Document': The tag name provided
>   ('/static/media/archive-solid.3c305173.svg') is not a valid name.

Im using create react app 2.1.1 and antd version 3.10.3
I would not want to do the create react app eject and i dont access to webpack
any ideas.
that the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Layout, Menu, Icon } from "antd";
import ArchiveSVG from "../../../img/icons/archive-solid.svg";

const { Sider } = Layout;

class SideBar extends Component {
state = {
  collapsed: false
};

onCollapse = collapsed => {
  this.setState({ collapsed });
};

render() {
 return (
   <Sider
     collapsible
     collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
     onCollapse={this.onCollapse}
   >
     <div className={styles.logo} />
     <Menu theme="dark" defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]} mode="inline">
       <Menu.Item key="4">
         <Icon component={ArchiveSVG} />
         <span>Products</span>
       </Menu.Item>
     </Menu>
   </Sider>
 );
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `archive-solid.svg` located? Outside of `src/` folder?

Comment: have you tried this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344200/import-multiple-similar-svg-sources-in-create-react-app-efficiently

Answer (score 3):

This method worked for me

```
import ArchiveSVG from "../../../img/icons/archive-solid.svg";

const archive = () => (
   <img src={ArchiveSVG} />
);
```

Then use like this

```
<Icon component={archive} />
```

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
import Icon from '@ant-design/icons';
import { ReactComponent as USAFlagIcon } from "./usa-flag.svg";

const USFlag = () => <Icon component={USAFlagIcon} />
```

Also to change the color of custom icon you need to remove SVG attributes. (I'm using [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/361) .. *[how to us it?](https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/361#issuecomment-103429776) *[config file](https://github.com/svg/svgo/blob/master/examples/test.js) )

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your svg and export is as JSX like following

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M8.309 189.836L184.313 37.851C199.719 24.546 224 35.347 224 56.015v80.053c160.629 1.839 288 34.032 288 186.258 0 61.441-39.581 122.309-83.333 154.132-13.653 9.931-33.111-2.533-28.077-18.631 45.344-145.012-21.507-183.51-176.59-185.742V360c0 20.7-24.3 31.453-39.687 18.164l-176.004-152c-11.071-9.562-11.086-26.753 0-36.328z">
    </path>
</svg>
```

and then use is like

```
<Icon component={RepySVG} />
```

Please create a code pen for more help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines to your `webpack.config.js`, so as to import SVG as a component directly.

```
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: '@svgr/webpack',
                        options: {
                            babel: false,
                            icon: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }
```

[Related doc](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/icon/index.en-US.md)