# How to override the default svg icons of antd used in the componens?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to override the default svg icons used in the antd library used in the components like TimePicker, DatePicker. etc. It used to have option in the less variable where i can set the @icon-url. But since the new update using svg instead of fontIcon, the option is gone.

It's available in version 2 https://2x.ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme
but not in 3 https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

Comment: share the library versions that worked and where it is not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322676/how-to-import-svg-into-antd-icon-component/55415583#55415583

Answer (score 5):

You can override icon path with your favorite in css file:

```
.anticon-foo svg path {
  d: path('M872 474H286.9l350.2-304c5.6-4.9 2.2-14-5.2-14h-88.5c-3.9 0-7.6 1.4-10.5 3.9L155 487.8a31.96 31.96 0 0 0 0 48.3L535.1 866c1.5 1.3 3.3 2 5.2 2h91.5c7.4 0 10.8-9.2 5.2-14L286.9 550H872c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-60c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8z');
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what `d:path()` mean? Is it a function call ?

Comment: d attribute defines a path to be drawn, and is one of path tag attributes.

Comment: it works well on Chrome but, d: path is not working with Safari - it said Unsupported property name